# Fails to reshape a vector into a matrix

Tags: r

I tried to reshape a vector `y` into a matrix `yy`, but it fails to do so:

```
> dim(y)
[1] 192   1
> class(y)
[1] "matrix"
> yy=as.matrix(y, nrow = 16, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
> dim(yy)
[1] 192   1
```

I wonder where I am wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Use `matrix` instead of `as.matrix`. If you look at the code for `as.matrix.default`, if the input is a matrix it just returns it untouched

Comment: Thanks!When will as.matrix work then?

Comment: Look at `methods(as.matrix)` to see all of the different methods

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a matrix `y`:

```
> y <- matrix(1, 192, 1:192)
> dim(y)
[1] 192   1
> class(y)
[1] "matrix"
```

You can reshape it with the `matrix()` function:

```
> newy <- matrix(y, nrow = 16, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
> dim(newy)
[1] 16 12
> class(newy)
[1] "matrix"
```

As for your follow-up question concerning when `as.matrix()` works, here's one way. First create a vector `x`:

```
> x <- 1:192
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
```

Now you can turn this vector into a matrix with `as.matrix()`:

```
> newx <- as.matrix(x)
> dim(newx)
[1] 192   1
> class(newx)
[1] "matrix"
```